# How to add/insert a new row in UITableView using user input

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

self.alphabets is my data source which contains all the alphabets.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    [tableView beginUpdates];
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.alphabets removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {

        [self.alphabets insertObject:[self.alphabets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] atIndex:[self.alphabets count]-1];

        NSIndexPath * path1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];

        NSArray * index = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path1, nil];

        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:index withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
    [tableView endUpdates];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.alphabets);
}
```

This is the code, which i am using to add or insert rows/cells in tableview by using the data already present.

But i want to add or insert a new row/cell by taking the user input. How to do it.

I have tried to use UIAlertController. Is that a right approach? But i failed. Someone please help me.

Also, i have a doubt about inserting multiple rows at a time. How to achieve it.

Here is the code which i am using to insert multiple rows at a time.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {  
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {

                [self.alphabets insertObject:[self.alphabets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] atIndex:[     self.alphabets count]-1];

                NSIndexPath * path1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];
                NSIndexPath * path2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:0];

                NSArray * index = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path1,path2, nil];

                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:index                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                }
                [tableView endUpdates];
                NSLog(@"%@",self.alphabets);
    }
```

Here is the exception i am getting.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (11) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (2 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: I guess self.alphabets is your datasource right? And could you also show us the error you're getting?

Comment: @Mahesh are you looking for design help (how the screen should look to get the user data) or coding help (you already have a way to get the user input, you're just not sure how to code adding it to the table)?

Comment: @SanderSaelmans yes, self.alphabets is my datasource. It contains all alphabets (A, B, C etc.,.) 

I am not getting any errors in the first part of code. But the problem is i want to insert a new row/cell by taking input from the user.

Comment: @fbara No, i am not looking for design help. I am looking for help, to insert a new cell or row by taking the user input. (e.g just like adding a new contact)

Comment: @fbara Somehow i have managed to achieve it. But, can you guys help me with inserting multiple rows at a time. But, not by reloading the tableview.

Comment: @SanderSaelmans can you help me with inserting multiple rows at a time. But, not by reloading the tableview.

Comment: I think the error pretty self-explanatory: the data source is inconsistent with the tableview. You insert only one new element into the data source, but two into the tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {

    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Inserting a new row" message:@"Enter text below to add it to table view" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {
    }];

    UIAlertAction * ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        NSArray * tfArray = alert.textFields;
        UITextField * tf = [tfArray objectAtIndex:0];
        self.userInput = tf.text;
        NSLog(@"%@",self.userInput);
        [self.alphabets insertObject:self.userInput atIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:NO completion:nil];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",self.alphabets);
}
```

Using the above code, I am able to add or insert new rows or cells with user input.

I used a UIAlertController to complete this task. I added a UITextfield to the alert controller and can now get input from it. It in turn adds it to the datasource and the reloaded UITableview.

`self.userInput` is an string used to store the user input given through a textfield in an alert.

If anyone thinks that this code can be improved, then let me know. I am always willing to improve myself.